# Backbone router with custom default route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, backbone-routing

I want to initiate a backbone app on the view, which is already rendered by Rails.

Here is my router code

```
class App.Routers.Dashboard extends Backbone.Router
 routes:
  '': 'index'
  'locations/:id': 'showLocation'

  index: ->
     alert "Dashboard page"

  initialize: ->
    @route(/\/?/, 'index', @index);
```

Then inside the rendered view, I initiate the app

```
$ ->
 App.appRouter = new App.Routers.Dashboard()
 Backbone.history.start
  pushState: true
  root: "/dashboard"
```

However, if I open the page

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard
```

the router does not enter the "index" state.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Having a default route of `''` will only match when the URL is at the root.

In your example, the "index state" will only be called with a url of `http://localhost:3000/`.

The recommended way to accomplish this is to use a "splat" route `'*path': 'index'`. Because this route effectively says to match anything, you will want to ensure that it is the last route defined.